# How can I disable js suggestions during TypeScript editing

Tags: resharper

While editing TypeScript files and using the "Search for usages" feature for example I only need references from .ts files but get a lot more from .js files. I tried ignoring the `node_modules` folder under "Code Inspections" -> "Settings" -> "Elements to Skip" but I get an "Folder not in solution" error. Why are there reference suggestions from a folder that isn't part of the project. Can I turn this off?

Even when it lets me add a folder (like `wwwroot\lib`) Resharper still shows me usages from files within the ignored folder.

I don't want to completely ignore all .js files via the "File masks" settings because I have some files like `gulpfile.js` that should get analyzed.

Also I'd like to ignore all .js files in a certain folder (like the output files from TypeScript) but I think the file mask pattern doesn't support directories.

Disabling the "JavaScript and TypeScript" feature under "Products & Features" obviously isn't a solution either.

Also editing ts files is very slow because I think Resharper has a huge analysis context from all the lib files.

I know that resharper knows the difference between usages in the solution and other usages because it groups the results in "in solution", "dynamic usages in solution and libraries" and "possible dynamic usages in solution and libraries". The question is how to ignore the latter two for TypeScript?

Using Resharper 2016.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper 2016.3 allows to fully ignore files.

Go to to the new option via ReSharper options -> "Code Editing" -> "Third-Party Code" -> "Skipped code".

Also it seems that files from non-solution folders (like node_modules) are excluded automatically now.